# Как узнать какой браузер у юзера?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, opera

navigator. userAgent

Данный способ не помогает, какие есть способы получить точное название браузера?

Comment: А чем вам это не помогло? У меня выдает название браузера `console.log(navigator.userAgent)`: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0`

Comment: я тестил этот момент в браузерах  опера, опера гх, хром, edge, и везде одинаковый ответ

Answer (score 2):

```
getBrowser = () => {
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    let browser = 'unkown';
    // Detect browser name
    browser = /ucbrowser/i.test(userAgent) ? 'UCBrowser' : browser;
    browser = /edg/i.test(userAgent) ? 'Edge' : browser;
    browser = /googlebot/i.test(userAgent) ? 'GoogleBot' : browser;
    browser = /chromium/i.test(userAgent) ? 'Chromium' : browser;
    browser =
        /firefox|fxios/i.test(userAgent) && !/seamonkey/i.test(userAgent)
            ? 'Firefox'
            : browser;
    browser =
        /; msie|trident/i.test(userAgent) && !/ucbrowser/i.test(userAgent)
            ? 'IE'
            : browser;
    browser =
        /chrome|crios/i.test(userAgent) &&
        !/opr|opera|chromium|edg|ucbrowser|googlebot/i.test(userAgent)
            ? 'Chrome'
            : browser;
    browser =
        /safari/i.test(userAgent) &&
        !/chromium|edg|ucbrowser|chrome|crios|opr|opera|fxios|firefox/i.test(
            userAgent
        )
            ? 'Safari'
            : browser;
    browser = /opr|opera/i.test(userAgent) ? 'Opera' : browser;

    // detect browser version
    switch (browser) {
        case 'UCBrowser':
            return `${browser}/${browserVersion(
                userAgent,
                /(ucbrowser)\/([\d\.]+)/i
            )}`;
        case 'Edge':
            return `${browser}/${browserVersion(
                userAgent,
                /(edge|edga|edgios|edg)\/([\d\.]+)/i
            )}`;
        case 'GoogleBot':
            return `${browser}/${browserVersion(
                userAgent,
                /(googlebot)\/([\d\.]+)/i
            )}`;
        case 'Chromium':
            return `${browser}/${browserVersion(
                userAgent,
                /(chromium)\/([\d\.]+)/i
            )}`;
        case 'Firefox':
            return `${browser}/${browserVersion(
                userAgent,
                /(firefox|fxios)\/([\d\.]+)/i
            )}`;
        case 'Chrome':
            return `${browser}/${browserVersion(
                userAgent,
                /(chrome|crios)\/([\d\.]+)/i
            )}`;
        case 'Safari':
            return `${browser}/${browserVersion(
                userAgent,
                /(safari)\/([\d\.]+)/i
            )}`;
        case 'Opera':
            return `${browser}/${browserVersion(
                userAgent,
                /(opera|opr)\/([\d\.]+)/i
            )}`;
        case 'IE':
            const version = browserVersion(userAgent, /(trident)\/([\d\.]+)/i);
            // IE version is mapped using trident version
            // IE/8.0 = Trident/4.0, IE/9.0 = Trident/5.0
            return version
                ? `${browser}/${parseFloat(version) + 4.0}`
                : `${browser}/7.0`;
        default:
            return `unknown/0.0.0.0`;
    }
};

browserVersion = (userAgent, regex) => {
    return userAgent.match(regex) ? userAgent.match(regex)[2] : null;
};

console.log(getBrowser());
```